# Rails, redactor and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, wysiwyg, redactor

I just came across RedActor (http://redactorjs.com/), a WYSIWYG-editor. I want to use it in combination with Rails and Paperclip but I don't know where to start. I searched the docs and came across PHP examples for uploading files and images.

Google found nothing for me. (Keywords: Rails Paperclip RedActor). I found this gem (https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails) on GitHub but it only offers integration with ActiveRecord and CarrierWave.

What do I have to do to get RedActor working together with Ruby On Rails and Paperclip?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm Sammy and redactor-rails developer.

The redactor-rails gem is only offers integration with ActiveRecord and CarrierWave now.

In future, I will offers integration with paperclip.

Please wait some time.

https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails/issues?state=open

Commit issues if there's anything else i can do to assist you!